# Is Fantastic Beasts and Where to Find Them an exhaustive list of magical animals in the Harry Potter world?

Tags: harry-potter, magical-creatures, fantastic-beasts-companion-book

*Fantastic Beasts and Where to Find Them* is a pseudo in-universe book describing magical animals from the Harry Potter world.

Is it an exhaustive list though? Do other creatures exist that don't feature in the book?

I'm asking because of this [comment](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/14542/where-did-voldemort-find-nagini/14833#comment52490_14833), by Gabe Willard:

> No creatures matching her description are listed in Fantastic Beasts and Where to Find Them. If you can, make an answer. I'm fairly confident she's a Muggle snake, however. **Such an absence from FBWFT would be unexpected**.

Emphasis mine.

Is such an absence unexpected? Are other 'well known' creatures that aren't featured in that book?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I do think it's particularly telling that Nagini -- the kind of snake she is -- is missing from *Fantastic Beasts and Where to Find Them*. There are magical snakes listed in *FBAWTFT*, such as the Ashwinder and the Runespoor. I agree with Gabe in that Nagini is a Muggle snake -- a Naga snake, to be specific (a snake which has mythical properties according to Hindu legend, and most resembles a giant cobra). I find it *interesting*, though, that Voldemort would choose a Muggle snake for himself. That seems telling in some way, although how I'm not sure.

Anyway, there are creatures missing from *FBAWTFT* that are mentioned in the novels:

- Hinkypunks
- Blast-ended Skrewts (Hagrid somehow invented these creatures, but one was included in the third task of the Triwizard Tournament, which gives it legitimacy).
- Animagus (this one is iffy, but if a werewolf is listed, I think an Animagus might be worth a mention. However, Animagi turn into Muggle animals, not magical creatures, so it's quite likely this wouldn't apply. Because, really. Being a unicorn Animagus would be *so* Mary Sue).
- Blood-Sucking Bugbears
- House-elves
- Double-ended newts
- Boggarts
- Owls (Owls in Potterverse have some unique qualities, such as being able to find anyone anywhere and the ability to not be tracked. They also want payment for their services. They're just different than Muggle owls)
- Ghosts, spirits, and poltergeists
- Veela
- Hags
- Giants
- Goblins
- Dementors
- Nargles¹
- Crumple-Horned Snorkack¹
- Unknown Creatures in the Lestranges' vault at Gringotts: *[T]he door of the vault melted away to reveal a cave-like opening crammed from floor to ceiling with golden coins and goblets, silver armour, **the skins of strange creatures, some with long spines, others with drooping wings***[.] (These could obviously be skins of already known creatures which are simply not identified as such)

¹Kidding, kidding ...

Comment: How could we forget the Nargles? lol

Comment: Didn't Voldie's soul shard inhabit a number of snakes while he was recovering at some point? I seem to remember reading that somewhere. IIRC, he could bond with them easily, because he always had an affinity with snakes, due to his Parseltongue.

Comment: @GabeWillard - Yes. While he was hiding out in the forest, presumably the one in Albania, he did inhabit the bodies of animals: *'I sometimes inhabited animals – snakes, of course, being my preference[.]'* I think Voldemort had an affinity with snakes from the time he was a small child. When he was still Tom Riddle, eleven, and in the orphanage, he says to Dumbledore, *'[Snakes] find me, they whisper to me. Is that normal for a wizard?’* So not only is Voldemort drawn towards snakes, they are drawn to him as well. :)

Comment: I thought House Elves and Goblins and a few others are omitted from the book because they are not classified as Beasts for a political reason.  That's just like how humans used to be excluded from older DnD monster manual books, despite that in game mechanic terms they behaved like monsters.

Comment: @b_jonas - It's a little tricky, yes, for some of the beasts/beings. In *FBAWTFT*, a "being" is classified as one who can speak the human tongue. Goblins and House-elves would fall into this category, as would jarveys. There is a Goblin Liaison office in the Ministry of Magic, as well as a House-elf Relocation Department. They are all seen as *beings* rather than beasts. If you read the introduction to *FBAWTFT*, the Goblins are mentioned. I don't *think* House-elves are mentioned either, but we've already established that not all beings/beasts are included in *FBAWTFT*. :)

Comment: @b_jonas - The political issue, I think, came from the centaurs. Although they were classified as beings by the Ministry, they chose to remain classified as beasts and chose to self-govern. Apparently there is a Centaur Office in the Ministry of Magic; the centaurs have never once utilized its services. So getting assigned to the Centaur Office apparently means you're probably going to get sacked in the near future :P  :)

Comment: I must request a refund from this book since it is flawed due to the absence of Crumple-Horned Snorkacks. I want my money back.

Comment: @Omega - I know, right? Hermione was convinced Xenophilius had an Erumpent horn, but just because it *happened* to blow up proves nothing except that it was an especially volatile horn, and while the Crumple-Horned Snorkack is a quiet and reserved creature normally, it's been known to blow its stack here and there ;)

Comment: Blast-ended Skrewts *were* bred by Hagrid, but *after* the book (FBWFT) was written; explaining why they weren't included. Another reason is that he *illegally* bred them.

Comment: note: There are no "muggle snakes". They're just snakes. It is true, that they don't have magical powers, but if for example chair doesn't have any magical powers it doesn't mean that it is "muggle" chair, it is just a chair (or we can say a regular chair). Probably even a Voldemort uses regular chairs and similary he has a regular snake.

Answer (score 8):

Yes, it's likely that not all the magical creatures known to the wizarding world were included in this textbook.

A list of magical creatures included in the book: http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/Fantastic_Beasts_and_Where_to_Find_Them

Off the top of my head, Basilisks, Boggarts, and Thestrals are not explicitly included on that list. Considering that this was meant as a textbook for the classroom, I would assume that only relatively common creatures of the wizarding world would've been included as an introduction to the topic of magical beasts and where to find them.

As a side note, remember that Voldemort was a [parselmouth](http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/Parseltongue). Nagini wouldn't have to be a magical snake for Voldemort to communicate with the snake and get it to do his bidding.

Comment: Basilisks and Thestrals are in *FBAWTFT*; Thestrals can be found under Winged Horses. You're definitely right about the Boggart, though. Technically, Voldemort (and Harry) is a Parselmouth. Parseltongue is the language that Parselmouths use to speak to snakes. </nerd>

Comment: I really like the textbook note. You should edit your answer as Slytherincess notes, but I think this answer is pretty useful.

Answer (score 8):

### Some creatures were left out at the request of the President of MACUSA

> At President Picquery’s request, I made no mention of the more important American magical creatures in the first edition of Fantastic Beasts, because she wished to deter wizarding sightseers. As the American wizarding community was subject to greater persecution at that time than their European counterparts, and given that I had inadvertently contributed to a serious breach of the International Statute of Secrecy in New York, I agreed.
>   <sub>*Fantastic Beast and Where to Find Them* (2017 textbook) - Foreword by the Author</sub>